# Check only specific field present in the string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to print the one of the following condition string if it contains **only** number field.

```
DECLARE @Condition varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323,12122'' AND Name=''Mak'''

DECLARE @Condition1 varchar(max) = 'Address=''UK'' AND Number =''12908'' AND Name=''Mak'''

DECLARE @Condition2 varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323'''
```

Note: The condition string is dynamic may comes with any number of fields but I want print it only if it contain number.

Expected Result: From the given condition2 should be print.

```
Number = '12908,13232323'
```

Comment: SQL Server isn't your friend for this; it's awful at string manipulation. If you need to do something like this, in your application is the right place. This (in truth) has the feel of XY Problem though.

Comment: Maybe an oversimplification, but could it be enough to just look for conditions that contain the word 'Number' and not the word 'AND' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a cte split function

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_string_split](@str NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @delimiter NVARCHAR(255))
returns table
as
return
WITH a AS(
        SELECT CAST(0 AS BIGINT) as idx1,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str) idx2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT idx2+1,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,idx2+1)
        FROM a
        WHERE idx2>0
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,idx1,COALESCE(NULLIF(idx2,0),LEN(@str)+1)-idx1) as value, row_number() over (Order by idx1) RN
    FROM a
```

This was then leveraged against your data to identify number of conditions in each string, and then filter.

```
DECLARE @Condition varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323,12122'' AND Name=''Mak'''

DECLARE @Condition1 varchar(max) = 'Address=''UK'' AND Number =''12908'' AND Name=''Mak'''

DECLARE @Condition2 varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323'''

DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (ID INT, Condition varchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(0,@Condition),(1,@Condition1),(2,@Condition2);

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT T.*, C.value,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) Cnt
FROM @Table T
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_string_split(Condition,'AND') C 
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE Cnt=1 AND LEFT(REPLACE(value,' ',''),7) = 'Number='
```

Could do with some more tweaking to exclude outlying cases but hopefully this will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Using Like to find 'Number' without 'AND'.

```
DECLARE @Condition varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323,12122'' AND Name=''Mak'''
DECLARE @Condition1 varchar(max) = 'Address=''UK'' AND Number =''12908'' AND Name=''Mak'''
DECLARE @Condition2 varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323'''
```

Query

```
Select conditions From (Values (@Condition),(@Condition1),(@Condition2)) c(conditions)
Where conditions Like '%Number%' And conditions Not Like '%AND%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following and does the job done.

```
DECLARE @Condition varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323,12122'' AND Name=''Mak'''

DECLARE @Condition1 varchar(max) = 'Address=''UK'' OR Number =''12908'' AND Name=''Mak'''

DECLARE @Condition2 varchar(max) = 'Number =''12908,13232323'''

IF REPLACE(REPLACE(@Condition,' OR ',' @ '),' AND ',' @ ') NOT LIKE '%@%' 
BEGIN
    PRINT(@Condition);
END
ELSE IF REPLACE(REPLACE(@Condition1,' OR ',' @ '),' AND ',' @ ') NOT LIKE '%@%' 
BEGIn
    PRINT(@Condition1);
END
ELSE IF REPLACE(REPLACE(@Condition2,' OR ',' @ '),' AND ',' @ ') NOT LIKE '%@%'  
BEGIn
    PRINT(@Condition2);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT('none');
END
```